# log4j2 in JNLP results Classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, jnlp

we have an old desktop application which was running on log4j. this application gets deployed using JNLP on the users system and then is connecting to server at our end. we are in the process of upgrading the application to log4j2. we have upgraded the server side code and it works fine. for the JNLP side of code, though we have done all the changes and deployed the application properly we are ending up with an exception which we dont seem to find the cause off. any help here is appreciated..

the exception is as listed below..

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:429)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:525)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:272)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:246)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:395)
at com.abcxyz.core.log.Logger.<clinit>(Logger.java:150)
at com.abcxyz.core.log.DefaultLog4jHelper.<init>(DefaultLog4jHelper.java:91)
at com.abcxyz.core.log.DefaultLog4jHelper.initLogger(DefaultLog4jHelper.java:44)
at com.abcxyz.ui.main.CMS.<clinit>(CMS.java:115)
at com.abcxyz.ui.main.InitializeCMS.main(InitializeCMS.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

the exception point to a class file in the log4j-1.2.17.jar (our old jar). i am sure i dont have the old jar anywhere in the code or any part of the code referring the the old jarfile.
[image]

pasted below is the sysArgs section of the JNLP where i am referring to the new properties file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with JNLP, but according to your stacktrace, program cannot find. In Log4j2 package `org.apache.log4j`    was changed to `org.apache.logging.log4j`. As a result it is not available.

1. One of easiest solutions in your case - to use Log4j 1.x bridge (Here is [Migration guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html))
2. If you want to use current version add to `<argument>` param to use log4j2 impl  (by default it is uses `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl` configured for log4j 1.x)
   `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl`

Comment: thanks for your answer but in my case it was not the correct option.. i have found the solution. will give the details of the answer below. might be of use to someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

we have found the solution. in our case there were two issues

1. the jar signing was not proper. the jars have manifest files under the meta-inf folder. the value of this folder was corrupted. we manually edited the file and preserved the original values for everything except the SHA keys and then resigned these jar.
2. in the log4j2-api jar there is a log4j-character.properties file which was getting corrupted while signing the jar using ant script. after the signing we replaced this file in the jar with the copy of the file saved from before the signing.

above to steps resolved our issue. i know what i wrote above might not make much sense to someone. happy to provide screen grabs in case on demand someone comes across this issue.